# Automatically link collection of reports with an existing data source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Is there a way to connect 100 SSRS reports with T-SQL, so I don't have to connect them manually one at a time?

Comment: What version of SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done through T-SQL. There is a utility called Reporting Services Scripter that will help you: [Reporting Services Scripter Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20120830141644/http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62)

In future - use a shared data source :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any VB skills you could use the SSRS [rs Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx) to execute a VB script against the Reporting Services web service that iterated through the reports and set the data source programatically using the [SetItemDataSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setitemdatasources.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method of the web service.